# SignatureDoesNotMatch - Amazon S3 API

Tags: php, amazon-s3, file-upload, upload

I am using a PHP class for Amazon S3 and CloudFront - [Link](https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class). But when I try to upload a file into a bucket, I get this error:

> [SignatureDoesNotMatch] The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you sign up for Amazon, you can create yourself a key pair (Amazon calls those access key ID and secret access key).

Those two are used to sign requests to Amazon's webservices. Amazon re-calculates the signature and compares if it matches the one that was contained in your request. That way the secret access key never needs to be transmitted over the network.

If you get "Signature does not match", it's highly likely you used a wrong secret access key. Can you double-check access key and secret access key to make sure they're correct?

Comment: in my case there was some extra whitespace in the config file/setting which had the secret key, so it was transmitting an extra `tab` character in the "password", thus invalidating the signature.

Comment: I had this same issue. It turned out the debugging tool I was using was mistakingly sending GET requests when the signature specified POST. This threw me off to thinking something was wrong with my signature encodings. Dumb mistake took up almost a day of trial and error.

Answer (score 5):

Personally I received this error because of the characters that were in my meta data.

The problematic character was the "–" chracter which is "\u2013" in unicode and different to "-".

```
$result = $s3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'       => $bucket,
    'Key'          => $keyname,
    'Metadata' => [
        'name' => 'Terminology – Blah'
    ]
));
```

A note from the documentation 
**http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#UserMetadata**...

> Amazon S3 stores user-defined metadata in lowercase. Each name, value
>   pair must conform to US-ASCII when using REST and UTF-8 when using
>   SOAP or browser-based uploads via POST.

Comment: ditto - when adding Metadata with a key 'Cache-Control' onto an object that already has a metadata key 'cache-control' I get this error.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error with `putObject()` when specifying a `Key` starting with slash character (`/`) - after removing the slash it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why AWS returns this error is usually that the **secret key** is **incorrect**