# s3 isn't uploading file and getting error of SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

I'm trying to add images to my s3 bucket in aws, but it doesn't seem to work. I get the error of `SignatureDoesNotMatch`

Here's how I'm uploading the file/image:

FrontEnd

```
const file = e.target.files[0];
const fileParts = file.name.split('.');
const fileName = fileParts[0];
const fileType = fileParts[1];
const response = axios.post('api/aws/sign_s3', { fileName, fileType );
```

Backend

```
router.post('/sign_s3', async (req, res) => {
    aws.config.update({
        accessKeyId: config.aws.accessKey,
        secretAccessKey: config.aws.secretKey,
        region: 'us-west-1'
    });

    const s3 = new aws.S3(); // Create a new instance of S3
    const fileName = req.body.fileName;
    const fileType = req.body.fileType;

    const s3Params = {
        Bucket: config.aws.bucketName,
        Key: fileName,
        Expires: 500,
        ContentType: fileType,
        ACL: 'public-read'
    };

    s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) return res.send(err);

        const returnData = {
            signedRequest: data,
            url: `https://sim-to-do.s3.amazonaws.com/${fileName}`
        };
        res.json({ success: true, responseData: returnData });
    });

});
```

I get two urls. When I go to the first one, I get the following error code:

> SignatureDoesNotMatch

Error Message

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

What am I doing wrong? What's the correct way of uploading a file to aws s3?

Comment: The issue is that you are setting the extension as the `ContentType` which is by definition wrong. E.g. instead of `jpg` you should set `image/jpg` as `ContentType`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue after removing the `Content-Type` from the headers.

Answer (score -3):

> If you get "Signature does not match", it's highly likely you used a wrong secret access key. Can you double-check access key and secret access key to make sure they're correct?

from [awendt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/473467/awendt) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281557/signaturedoesnotmatch-amazon-s3-api)